# Xdebug 3 / PHP / VS Code / Win10 - Not opening in browser properly - any ideas what's wrong?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I've installed XAMPP (control panel 3.3.0) on my Windows 10 PC. I then installed VS Code (v1.74.3)

I ran the `phpinfo()` and pasted the results into the Xdebug wizard and followed the instructions on that page (downloaded `php_xdebug-3.2.0-8.2-vs16-x86_64.dll`, renamed as `php_xdebug.dll` and saved to `C:\xampp\php\ext`)

I then added the following to `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` file.

```ini
zend_extension = xdebug
```

I restarted the Apache server and VS Code. I also installed the PHP Debug (v1.30) extension to VS Code.

When I load up a test PHP file and try to debug it, it seems to work as expected in VS Code (it stops at breakpoints, I can step through, the variables pane updates, and echo'd text appears in the debug console. This is when I do "launch currently open script").

But when I do "launch built-in web server", to see what it looks like in a browser, it opens Chrome to `http://localhost:62xxx/` (the number changes each time) and the page says:

> **Not Found**
> The requested resource / was not found on this server.

I've probably just missed a setup/config step somewhere.  How do I get it to open a browser that shows what the script is outputting?

Comment: *"But when I do "launch built-in web server""* This should use PHP's own built-in web server. Why don't you use your Apache if you have one? A proper webserver is always better than a more simple built-in one.

Comment: Does running that file actually use the configuration you changed? Check e.g. what `phpinfo()` says. Also, your Q is a bit confusing, because that error doesn't seem to have any relation to Xdebug but only to how you serve files using PHP's builtin webserver.

Comment: How/where do I configure it to use apache (which is installed as part of xampp)?  The issue here is that xampp/xdebug/vscode is all new to me, and I'm just trying to configure them all to work together.